# Maven build failure: Failed to execute goal on project. Could not resolve dependencies. Can't resolve issue with codehaus

Tags: maven, mule

I have a Mule 3.6.1 project with an Eclipse plugin. When running unit tests within Mule using Junit, the tests are running. However, executing the tests using `mvn test` on the terminal produces the following errors:

```
Failed to execute goal on project edus-esb-activity-aggregator: Could not 
resolve dependencies for project edu.ucdavis.iet.edus:edus-esb-activity- 
aggregator:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at 
org.mule.modules:mule-module-apikit:jar:1.5.2 -> org.mule.modules:mule-
module-cors:jar:1.2 -> org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-config:jar:3.4.0 
-> org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.4.0 -> javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1-osgi:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1-
osgi: Could not transfer artifact javax.activation:activation:pom:1.1-osgi 
from/to codehaus-releases (http://repository.codehaus.org/): 
repository.codehaus.org: nodename nor servname provided, or not known: 
Unknown host repository.codehaus.org: nodename nor servname provided, or not
known
```

I have already made sure that the project contains all the jars listed in the error message. The build failure occurs when maven tries to download http://repository.codehaus.org/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1-osgi/dom4j-1.6.1-osgi.pom. Referencing **http://www.codehaus.org/mechanics/maven/** I have modified Maven's settings.xml file to be:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>codehaus-mule-repo</id>
                    <name>codehaus-mule-repo</name>
                    <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1-osgi/dom4j-1.6.1-osgi.pom</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Unfortunately this still doesn't resolve the issue. Finally, here are the dependencies in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-artifact-archiver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
        <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mnode.ical4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>ical4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
        <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.28-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-objectstore</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-mongo</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-json</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm not sure how to move forward, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because [Codehaus is no more](http://www.codehaus.org/) :(

Thankfully they have some [migration help](http://www.codehaus.org/mechanics/maven/) at least.

Comment: The build failure occurs when maven attempts to download http://repository.codehaus.org/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1-osgi/dom4j-1.6.1-osgi.pom. Using the migration help page I added https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1-osgi/dom4j-1.6.1-osgi.pom to settings.xml (shown in original post), but unfortunately that hasn't resolved the issue. Could you please check to see if I did it properly?

Comment: Looks like it isn't trying your repo, but that's probably because you should name that profile and/or activate it by default (see [profiles reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html))

Answer (score 0):

Adding the repository as described in the [migration help](http://www.codehaus.org/mechanics/maven/) does not fix the issue in the case of mule dependencies.

One solution is to add the following repository:

```
<repository>
   <id>ibiblio-mule</id>
   <name>ibiblio Mule dependencies</name>
   <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven/mule/dependencies/maven2</url>
   <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```